# Characteristic of a ring: $\ker(\varphi) = (n)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, ring-homomorphism

I've been asked to prove that there is exactly one ring homomorphism from the ring of integers to any ring with unity. And I proved that let $R$ be a ring with unity and 
$$
\begin{array}{rccl}
\varphi \colon & \mathbb{Z} & \longrightarrow & R\\
&z  & \longmapsto & \varphi(z)=z \cdot 1_R, 
\end{array}
$$
$\varphi$ is the unique posible homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $R$.

The second part of the exercise ask: **"Show that $\exists \,n \in \mathbb{N}$ shuch that $\ker(\varphi) = (n)$, where $(n) = \{n \cdot k \, \mid \, k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ without using the definition of characteristic of a ring R"**.

Comment: You know the kernel will be a subgroup (and actually an ideal) of $\mathbb{Z}$. Do you know the form of these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kernel of a ring homomorphism is an ideal.  The only ideals in $\Bbb Z$ are of the form $(n)$.

That is, $\Bbb Z$ is a PID.

Comment: If we define characteristic of a ring as "the natural number n such that nZ is the kernel of the unique ring homomorphism from Z to R", how can I prove that $Char(\mathbb{R}) = 0$?

Comment: @user152985 There is a unique ring morphism $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$, which is the inclusion map. This is injective, and thus the kernel is $(0)$. Thus $\operatorname{Char}(\mathbb{R})=0$.

Comment: @ε-δ I guess $Char(\mathbb{C})=0$ for the same reason?

Comment: @user152985 Yes. Exactly. Actually, a ring has characteristic zero if and only we can embed $\mathbb{Z}$ in it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the kernel of that ring homomorphism is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$. In particular, it must be a subgroup of the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}$. But subgroups of cyclic groups are again cyclic, so there is $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that

$$\ker \varphi = n \mathbb{Z}$$

**Example**: There is a unique ring morphism $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$, which is the inclusion map. This is injective, and thus the kernel is $(0)$. Thus $\operatorname{Char}(\mathbb{R})=0$.